# How to access gradle variable in thymeleaf template?

Tags: gradle, thymeleaf, continuous-deployment

I have simple web project with gradle and I wish to obtain gradle variable in thymeleaf template like:
Updated part of Thymeleaf template
`<title>Simple project title v.: @myVar@-beta</title>`

and in build.gradle I have this variable (updated after comments):
`import org.apache.tools.ant.filters.ReplaceTokens
def myVar = "dev"
... minimized ...
war {
    filter( ReplaceTokens, tokens: ['@myVar@': myVar])
}` where `dev` - is a custom value from my build server which is passing by
`gradle war -P myVar=122`.

How I can get it if this is possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wont be able to do this. Well... not the way you are trying to.
And then there is the thing that your code should not depend on the build tool.

What you **should do** instead is, get the build tool to inject the variable into your code.

I am sure your thymeleaf template is being copied from its location to some place else during build, at this point add a filter clause.

```
change
<title>Some title ${#myVar}</title>
to   
<title>Some title @myVar@</title>
```

and then

```
import org.apache.tools.ant.filters.ReplaceTokens // dont forget this import

war {
    filter(ReplaceTokens, tokens: [myVar: myVar])
}
```

Comment: And during build process I need only pass parameter in command line like: `gradle war -P myVar=126`?

Comment: Something not good. I'm setting up `war` task as you write including `import...` and on the build server passing arguments for gradle as `war -P myVar=${bamboo.buildNumber}` and in logs I see the correct command with numbers, and I receive the WAR archive, but in template my variable not changed. Here is a part of my build.gradle scenarios: `import org.apache.tools.ant.filters.ReplaceTokens
def myVar = "dev"
... minimized ....
war {
    filter( ReplaceTokens, tokens: ['@myVar@': myVar])
}`  Or I need define my variable locally in the WAR task?

Comment: Finally! I found where I have error! Over `-P` flag for Gradle I can only pass variables which isn't defined in `build.gradle` file. I have been remover line: `myVar = "dev"` from my gradle configuration and All work! Thank you, @Anup !